# Take one disk of external mdadm data raid 1 to travel

Tags: software-raid, read-only, mdadm

I have a mdadm software raid 1 on external disks with media data.

For travel I want to take the data with me.

I imagine to set the raid and the underlying filesystem in readonly mode and take just one disk with me. Is this possible?

**EDIT**

I tried to

```
mount -o ro /dev/sdc1 /mnt/test

mount: unbekannter Dateisystemtyp „linux_raid_member“
```

So the partition type is `Linux raid autodetect`  (the raid array is partitioned altogether as reiserfs

**EDIT 2**

having written the task, helped me to clear my mind. I think I have to run the same mdadm configuration in my laptop and just do a mdadm remove onedisk and mount the array like that and readonly. Any comments please?

Comment: Try it. If it works post it as an answer here and get som rep for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here's what I did :**

I copied the mdadm.conf to the laptop. But later removed that and did on that box a fresh

```
mdadm --detail --scan >> mdadm.conf
```

I don't know very much about the md device auto numbering: md127 when and why; If the name stored on the array; If the metadata has to match etc.

Anyway - I continued:  Plugged both disks and checked if array is active and both disks fine; Watched syslog so I saw which physical disk is which device.

Then marked as read-only, but found out I cannot mark disk as failed / remove disk in ro state so I remarked as rw

then

```
mdadm /dev/md0 -f /dev/sdc2
mdadm /dev/md0 -r /dev/sdc2
```

Plugged off that disk I removed. ( I have one disk pair with two arrays on it - I had to care to do these steps for both arrays and then plug off; Another 2TB disk pair with one array was simpler )

Tested mounting / unmounting / plugging-off / replugged / mount  - as root and via palimpsest : It asks if one wants to mount array in degraded state. - "Yes" and fine

Just not sure if mount points will be fine. Once I had the msg , mount point is missing - i created them manually

Good luck to anyone doing same thing. And good luck to me, re-assembling the arrays at home again in four weeks ... ;-)  -